# The order of intensives(such, so, too) with adjective and noun

Tags: adverbs

I'm a common non-English speaking person, who gets into English and cognitive linguistics.

I find some adverbs like "*so*", "*as*", and "*too*" precede articles, as follows

1. It is a very common error.
2. It is a extremely noisy city.
3. It is as red an apple as blood.
4. This is so good a question.
5. It is too expensive a desk for a child's room.

Most adverbs just stand in the middle of the noun phrase like *[a (very common) error]*.
However, "*so*", "*as*", and "*too*" escape with adjective! like *[(too expensive) a desk]* (even though it sounds formal or rare, and these adverbs are often used with only adjective)

And I think there must be a linguistic reason ;)
Syntactically, semantically, or any way..

I looked for books, papers, and any materials, but I couldn't find explanation for this.

I was wondering what is the power for them to escape!

You can just recommend a book or a paper if it's too long to talk here.

Thank you for your help, and if it's explained I would sleep in peace :))

Comment: Well, calling them adverbs won't help. _So_ and _such_ are parts of a determiner construction, the _so/such ... that_ `S` construction. _Such_ goes before noun phrases and _so_ goes elsewhere. _So_ is also used alone as an intensifier (_I'm **so** tired_), often stressed. _As_ is used in many idioms, and it's part of the equative _as ... as ..._ construction  (_as red as a rose_); used alone, it works like an adverb form of _be_ (_It's being used as a flowerpot_). Many of your sentences are incorrect in the idioms and constructions used. There are a lot of little details.

Comment: #3 is completely ungrammatical to me – needs to be “It is an apple as red as blood” to be grammatical, but even then it’s highly unidiomatic. #4 is borderline ungrammatical (should be “That is such a good question”), but can be made grammatical by the addition of a second clause: “This is so good a question that I don’t think anyone can answer it” (though ‘such a good question’ or ‘this question is so good that…’) would still be more natural.

Comment: @jlawler but how about "This isn’t as unusual a construction as you think," which is said by a native speaker?

Comment: What about it? It's grammatical and meaningful. Is there something to object to?

Comment: @jlawler oh sorry I tagged you by mistake.. I should've tagged Janus... Cuz he said #3 is ungrammatical though "This isn't as unusual a construction as you think" is grammatical as you say.